# App crashing while fetching contact numbers from iPhone in SWIFT

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, abaddressbook

I am trying to get the contacts using the following code:

```
var addressBook: ABAddressBook!
let addressBookRef: ABAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil).takeRetainedValue()

var arrContacts = [""]
var personNameContactNo:[String: String] = ["":""]
var arrOfDictContacts = NSMutableArray()
var Name: String!

    if let people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSArray {

        for person in people{
            if let name = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as? String {
                Name = name
            }
            let numbers:ABMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(
                person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()
            var number = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers,0).takeRetainedValue() as! String

            println("number = \(number)")

            if(number.isEmpty) {
                println("empty")
            } else {
                personNameContactNo.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                personNameContactNo.updateValue(number, forKey:Name)
                arrOfDictContacts.addObject(personNameContactNo)
            }
            println(personNameContactNo)
        }
        println(arrOfDictContacts)
    }

what am expecting is: ["Arun":"123455"], ["John":"23456122"], etc...
```

It runs good in simulator but not on device. maybe it is due to some nil value.
 The app crashes with following msg: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)`

[image: Crashing Image]

Comment: Can you specify at what line your code is crashing?

Comment: I don't know which line, it didn't  point at the time crashing

Comment: try the code posted in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try; this should solve your problem.

```
var addressBookRef: ABAddressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil).takeRetainedValue()

var arrOfDictContacts:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

let people:NSArray = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef).takeRetainedValue();

for person in people{
        if  let name:String = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String {
            let numbers:ABMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()

//                if (ABMultiValueGetCount(numbers) > 0) {  //This condition is optional because using '?' before calling takeRetainedValue
                if let number:String = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers,0)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String {
                    println("number = \(number)");
                    arrOfDictContacts.addObject(["\(name)":"\(number)"]);
                }
//                }
        }
}
//--
println(arrOfDictContacts);
```

Comment: @Shoib still crashing with same error. added screenshot in question

Comment: @AAA I have updated my post. If it is still crashing, then use break points to find the line on which actually code is crashing.

Comment: ok, the app was neither crashing nor fetching any contacts. `arrOfDictContacts` is empty

Comment: reverting back. I'll need to test it on my own but right now don't have development environment. hopefully, will come back with a resolve.

Comment: thanks that was fetching all the contact name and number without crashing. But when I display it in my table view, the tableview is empty!! Y? and is there a way it can be sorted in alphabetical order?

Comment: Solved the issue. Thank You :)

Comment: See solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933706/loading-contacts-from-iphone-crashes-in-swift