# Null value returns from AddressBook framework in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, addressbookui

In my swift app, I am retrieving AddressBook contacts from AddressBook framework. Contacts are retrieved successfully except the following case.

**Case 1:**

If I save a contact number alone without contact name to AddressBook, contact is successfully added.

But, If I try to retrieve that contact which does not having name, App crashes, saying that **fatal error received.**

**Coding:**

```
var contactName: String = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(addressBookRecord).takeRetainedValue() as NSString as String
```

I don't know how to handle this null value exception. Kindly guide me, how to solve this.

Comment: Why don't you check if contactName returns null and assign it an empty string if that is the case? something like this http://paste.ubuntu.com/12695416/

Comment: You should take a look at the new contact framework https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html

Comment: App crashes on that line @NSNoob . Then how can I do that?

Comment: App crashes on the line you provided or on the checks?

Comment: Yes! App crashed on the above line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will not crash if you got any contact without name:

```
func processAddressbookRecord(addressBookRecord: ABRecordRef) {

    let addressBookRef: ABAddressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil).takeRetainedValue()

    let people:NSArray = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef).takeRetainedValue();

    for person in people{
        if  let name:String = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String {
            let numbers:ABMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()

            if let number:String = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers,0)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String {
                print("number = \(number)");
                arrayOfContacts.addObject(["\(name)":"\(number)"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Original post: [App crashing while fetching contact numbers from iPhone in SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422244/app-crashing-while-fetching-contact-numbers-from-iphone-in-swift)